# MapsterMapper mapping base class

Tags: c#, mapster

I am using Mapster for mapping my objects.

I have the the following code:

```
public sealed class User : AggregateRoot<UserId>
{
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }
    public string Email { get; }
    public string Password { get; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDateTime { get; }

    private User(UserId userId, string firstName, string lastName, string email, string password)
        : base(userId)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Email = email;
        Password = password;
        CreatedDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

```
public sealed class UserId : ValueObject
{
    public Guid Value { get; }

    private UserId(Guid value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

```
public record AuthenticationResult(
    User User,
    string Token
);
```

```
public record AuthenticationResponse(
    Guid Id,
    string FirstName,
    string LastName,
    string Email,
    string Token
);
```

```
public abstract class AggregateRoot<TId> : Entity<TId>
    where TId : notnull
{
    protected AggregateRoot(TId id) : base(id)
    {
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class Entity<TId> : IEquatable<Entity<TId>>
    where TId : notnull
{
    public TId Id { get; protected set; }

    protected Entity(TId id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        return obj is Entity<TId> entity && Id.Equals(entity.Id);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Entity<TId> left, Entity<TId> right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Entity<TId> left, Entity<TId> right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }

    public bool Equals(Entity<TId>? other)
    {
        return Equals((object?)other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterRequest request)
    {
        var command = _mapper.Map<RegisterCommand>(request);

        ErrorOr<AuthenticationResult> authResult = await _mediator.Send(command);

        return authResult.Match(
            authResult => Ok(_mapper.Map<AuthenticationResponse>(authResult)),
            errors => Problem(errors)
        );

    }
```

```
config.NewConfig<AuthenticationResult, AuthenticationResponse>()
            .Map(dest => dest, src => src.User);
```

I am trying to map the AuthenticationResult to the AuthenticationResponse but i get this error

---> Mapster.CompileException: Error while compiling source=FinanceManager.Domain.User.ValueObjects.UserId destination=System.Guid type=Map ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot convert immutable type, please consider using 'MapWith' method to create mapping

can anyone help me pls?

Comment: Please provide [mre]. What is `AggregateRoot`. Where is your mapping call that fails?

Comment: Added more information on main post

Comment: And code for `AggregateRoot`?

Comment: Sorry, there now

Comment: And `Entity`? =)

Comment: there too. =) ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to add the following mapping configuration:

```
TypeAdapterConfig<UserId, Guid>.NewConfig()
    .MapWith(id => id.Value);
```

Comment: @JorgeCardoso Was glad to help! (you can upvote to wink-wink =)